# get and post requests keep loading in postman/browser

Tags: node.js, mongoose, postman

I am using postman to test my API.I am sending get and post requests from postman but it keeps saying sending and there is no error and no response. Please, Tell me how to debug my code.
P.S. : I am new to Backend develpment.

**App.js file :**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const morgan = require('morgan');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
require('dotenv').config({ path: '.env' });

app.use(cors);
app.options('*', cors());

//Middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(morgan('tiny'));

//Routes
const productsRoutes = require('./routers/products');
const categoriesRoutes = require('./routers/categories');

const api = process.env.API_URL;
app.use(`${api}/products`, productsRoutes);
app.use(`${api}/categories`, categoriesRoutes);


//Database
mongoose.connect(process.env.CONNECTION_STRING, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
.then(()=>{
    console.log('Database connection is ready');
})
.catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err);
});

//Server
app.listen(3000, ()=>{
    console.log("Server is running on http://localhost:3000");
});
```

**category.js (category schema):**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const categorySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name :{
        type :String,
        required : true
    }, 
    icon :{
        type : String,
    },
    color :{
        type : String,
    }
})

exports.Category = mongoose.model('Category', categorySchema);
```

**categories.js**

```
const {Category} = require('../models/category');

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', async(req, res) =>{
    const categoryList = await Category.find();
    if(!categoryList){
        res.status(500).json({success: false})
    }
    res.stauts(200).send(categoryList);
})

router.post('/', async(req, res) =>{
    const category = new Category({
        name: req.body.name,
        icon: req.body.icon,
        color: req.body.color
    });
    category = await category.save();
    if(!category)
    return res.status(404).send('The category cannot be created');
    res.send(category);
})

module.exports = router;
```

Postman keep sending request:

[image: Postman screenshot]

Comment: Can you show the server log? Did you see the line `Database connection is ready` ? Also, can you add a `console.log('post category');` at the beginning of the post controller?

Comment: server is running and database connection is ready

Comment: resolved : syntax error in this line in app.js: app.use(cors);  correct : app.use(cors());

Answer (score 0):

syntax error in app.js: app.use(cors);
correct : app.use(cors());